# Issue with next/image in NextJS V12.3.0 specifically with alt attribute

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I use next/image to render images on the site and set the alt tag appropriately. The images I use originate from a CDN. I have a NextJS-based repository. The issue is that, despite the fact that the image is rendering correctly, whenever I check my site's Google cache and switch to the text-only version, Google attempts to replace the image with the text specified in the alt attribute, which is somehow repeating itself. As a result, instead of displaying "Some Image ALT," Google displays "Some Image ALTSome Image ALT."

Here's my implementation for reference:

```
<div className="videoCard__image">
  <Image
    src={bannerUrl}
    alt={titleLabel}
    layout="responsive"
    width={123.6}
    height={120}
    className="videoCard__image--banner"
    priority={loadPriority}
    sizes="33vw"
    quality={80}
  />
  <PlayCircleOutline className="videoCard__image--play-icon" />
</div>
```

Rendered image HTML from next/image ->
[Rendered image HTML from next/image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCyae.png)

Google cache text only version ->
[Google cache text only version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1PlK.png)

Expectation: ALT attributte text to occur to once instead of twice.

Comment: Hello Yatin, make sure you are passing correct props to the alt i.e `titleLabel`.. Cross check from where you are passing the value here.

Comment: Hello, all of the props have been verified and are accurate and titleLabel is this case comes as a non-repeated string. This only occurs when Google Cache is switched to the text-only version.